# Is the GMT time zone is same all over world?

Tags: php, time, timezone, gmt, centralized

My server is running PHP. I am using `gmdate()` function to insert records into my database from server. I just wonder whether time zone is centralized by using `gmdate()` function ?

Example:

> One user creates entry from India and record is inserted into database
>
> and
>
> Second user create entry from USA/canada/france and record is inserted into database.

Is that time will be same as I used `gmdate()` function while inserting record at server?

Comment: If you do an insert, the time seen by the database server is just the machine time - it does not take into account where your user is. With web applications, you generally access the database via just one user anyway, so the database server does not know where your users are. However, if you want Indian users to see timestamps based on their own timezone, then you'll need to allow them to set their timezone in a profile page, and you can take that into account when rendering times and dates.

Comment: So what is the machine time?

Comment: What I mean by "machine time" is the system clock, taking into account its timezone (which is configured in MySQL or PHP depending on where you get it from). Since you reference a PHP function, make sure your php.ini is correctly configured for your timezone.

Comment: So you want to say that I use only date() function rather than gmtdate function while inserting record?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to do. Let me assume your server is in India, and the PHP timezone is set correctly on that server. If you use `date` then your timestamps will be local, and if you use `gmdate` (not `gmtdate`) then your timestamps will be GMT. I would say that if all your servers are in India, use local, and if they are in various places, use GMT.

Comment: @halfer - I disagree.  It's never a good idea to store the local server time.

Comment: @Matt - fair enough, and good answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first of all, the function is called `gmdate`, not `gmtdate` or `gmatdate`.  But I will assume these to be typos.

GMT is an abbreviation for Greenwich Mean Time.  It's name is a bit confusing to some, as in Greenwich, England, UK, they follow GMT during the winter and BST (British Summer Time) during the summer.  This is the form of daylight saving time that is used in the UK.  But GMT *always* refers to the standard time, and never the daylight time.  In other words, GMT is a fixed time zone that does not follow daylight saving time, even though its physical locality does.

To clear up this but of confusion, we prefer to use the term UTC, which stands for Universal Coordinated Time (yes, the letters are out of sequence, and there's a reason for that, which is not relevant here).  UTC is a timekeeping system that is agreed upon as an international standard.  There are several parts to it's definition, but the important part here is that it defines its baseline as the same as GMT.  Or depending who you ask, GMT is now defined the same as UTC.  It doesn't matter - they are effectively the same.

And yes, no matter where in the world you are talking about it, you should get the same time when you use the `gmdate()` function to return it.

The important reason to use UTC is that a server application should never depend on any local time zone.  Who knows, one day you might pick up your data and move it to another location, or migrate it to the cloud, or interact with servers in other places.  When doing so, if your times are in UTC, then your point of reference is all the same so everything will work well.

On the other hand, if you store local times and then you move somewhere else, then all your data has to be updated.  Even if you never move - if your local time is somewhere like the USA or the UK or many other places, these places have daylight saving time as part of their time zone.  This means you could be storing local times that are ambiguous for at least one hour of each year.  That's not a good thing.

The alternative to UTC/GMT is to store a date+time+offset value.  Then you will know both the local time, and how it relates to UTC (by the offset).  But I would still reserve this for values where the local time is relevant.  I mean, who really cares what the server's local time is anyway?  If it carries no relevant business context, then you shouldn't introduce it into your application.

Comment: Side note - I could have just answered this question with, "YES" and a [link to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmt).  I didn't downvote the question, but I don't feel any particular need to upvote it.  Perhaps a bit more research is in order before you ask your next question.  Rule #1 for a great StackOverflow question is to do your own research first.

Comment: Thank you .So My doubt is clear now(whether gmdate() function returns same time at various places-> Yes,It returns same time.)